# phpoffice or any phpWord library that can add comment to a word document?

Tags: php, phpword, phpoffice

Is there any PHP Word Document Library that can allow me to add comments automatically,
Such as this sample below,

[image]

Wherein comments can be seen on the right side on the document,

I have tried PHPOffice but it doesn't seem to have any comment capabilities,

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
        $phpWord->setDefaultFontSize(10);
        $phpWord->setDefaultFontName('Calibri');
        $phpWord->setDefaultParagraphStyle(
            array(
            'spaceAfter' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::pointToTwip(0))
        );

$metaDataSection = $phpWord->addSection();
        $metaDataSection->addText(
            "Legal Name: "Sample Legal Name ",  
            array('bold' => true)
        );
$metaDataSection-> like addComment() functionality
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an [example](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_37_Comments.php) for doing exactly this on the PHPWord sources.

A fragment of the example is:

```
// Let's create a comment that we will link to a start element and an end element
$commentWithStartAndEnd = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Comment('Foo Bar', new \DateTime());
$commentWithStartAndEnd->addText('A comment with a start and an end');
$phpWord->addComment($commentWithStartAndEnd);

$textrunWithEnd = $section->addTextRun();
$textrunWithEnd->addText('This ');
$textToStartOn = $textrunWithEnd->addText('is', array('bold' => true));
$textToStartOn->setCommentRangeStart($commentWithStartAndEnd);
$textrunWithEnd->addText(' another', array('italic' => true));
$textToEndOn = $textrunWithEnd->addText(' test');
$textToEndOn->setCommentRangeEnd($commentWithStartAndEnd);
```

There is also some information in the [documentation](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elements.html#comments).